# How do I register Shell Namespace Extension in packaged app?

Tags: packaging, msix, shell-namespace-extension, windows-11

I need to deploy a [Shell Namespace Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/nse-implement) as part of my [packaging project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-extensions), created by Visual Studio. I see that I can register context menus, property handlers and COM exe and surrogate servers, but not Shell Namespace Extensions for some reason.

Is it possible to register a Shell Namespace Extension in a packaging project?

If not, are there any plans for extending the Package.appxmanifest schema to support them on Windows 11? Or are there any replacement for Shell Namespace Extension provided on Windows 11?